# API references for Kotlin Language

Tags: api, kotlin

Is there an official Kotlin API references like Java (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html)? Where it lists out all the functions, classes, interfaces etc by package?

This https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ seems pretty limiting.

Thanks

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/alltypes/ ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *limiting*. The link you put there is the official Kotlin's documentation.

Comment: I was hoping to get one like official java api reference where you got packages as expandable tree and the details of the class / methods / function details on the left hand side. Like https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity would be fine too. I guess the closes i could get is like what @Martheen mentoned.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right site, but you have to navigate to the standard library [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/). It also comes with buttons at the top where you can filter for availability on your platform. `actor` for example is not available in `common` projects.

Note that all this was generated by Dokka (the Kotlin equivalent of Javadoc), so you can also generate your own!